# Lua/print table error : ( attempt to concatenate a table value)

Tags: lua

I got a simple code like:

```lua
table = {}
print(table.."hello")
```

then got a error like the title. I know i need to use `tostring(table)` to fix it . Why table or other types can't convert to string to concatenate a String automatically except number type ?

`print(table)` is available But `print(table.."hello")` is not .

Does lua have some rules?

Thanks you.

Comment: The rules are at https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.6

Comment: I never see it before, thank you . @lhf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why table or other types can't convert to string to concatenate a String automatically except number type?

This is a deliberate choice made by the Lua language designers. Strings and numbers are [coerced](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.2.1): Every operation that expects a string will also accept a number and `tostring` it; every operation that expects a number will also accept a string and `tonumber` it.

Coercion is an operation applied to strings. Numbers will be `tostring`ed. Any other type won't. For other primitive types like bools and nils this is somewhat questionable, since they can be converted to string without issue. For tables it's reasonable though since they are a reference type.

Unlike other languages which make such decisions for you, Lua is highly metaprogrammable: You can simply override the decision! In this case, [metatables](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8) are the solution, specifically the [`__concat`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.4) metamethod which gets called if concatenation (`..`) is applied to two values of which one has the metamethod (and is neither a string or number):

```lua
table = setmetatable({}, {
    __concat = function(left, right)
        if type(left) == "string" then
            return left .. tostring(right)
        end
        return tostring(left) .. tostring(right)
    end
})
print(table .. "hello") -- hellotable: 0x563eb139bea0
```

You could even extend this to primitive types (nils, booleans), some other reference types (functions, coroutines) using `debug.setmetatable`, but I'd advise against this.

Comment: I really try to compare lua with other language like Java,Python to think about it . Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

1. The declaration of `table = {}` destroying the `table` library
2. The datatype `table` is not a string or number so concat with `..` must fail

Try this instead...

```
mytab = {}

table.insert(mytab, "hello")

print(table.concat(mytab))
```

For the `table` library functions look: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.6

Comment: it does not destroy the table library it only refers `table` to something else. also concatenation fails because table is neither a string nor a number value and does not have a metatable implementing `__concat`. not because it is a table value. I don't think table.concat is what the OP was looking for. btw how does table.concat make sense for a single element table?

Comment: Thank you . I actually use 'mytable' . Sorry for my bad example .